# Validation of WADL File

Tags: validation, wadl

Is there a way to validate a given WADL File?

Validating against the XML Schema won't catch all errors, since this will not catch errors like a method parameter with a wrong style or an undefined type.

I also tried the command line tool WADL2java from apache cxf, but this doesn't catch all violations of the wadl specification - and even if it would catch all errors, generating code just for the sake of validation seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 11):

1. Navigate to [online xml validator with xsd](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html)
2. copy-paste your wadl xml into the "XML Input Option 1" text field
3. Paste the [this](https://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/wadl.xsd) url into the "XSD Input Option 2" text field:
4. Click on "VALIDATE XML"